# Prove that atleast one of $x$, $y$, or $z$ is even when $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ ie that at least one number in a pythagorean triple is even.

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, proof-verification

I am wondering if what I have written is correct. Here is what I got:

We can prove this with proof by contradiction. Assuming that the contrary, that all numbers in a Pythagorean Triple is odd, we get that

$x = 2m_1 + 1, y = 2m_2 + 1, z = 2m_3 + 1$ where $m_1, m_2, m_3 \in \mathbb{Z}$.

$x^2 + y^2 = (2m_1 + 1)^2 + (2m_2 + 1)^2 = 4m_1^2 + 4m_1 + 4m_2^2 + 4m_2 + 2 = 2(2m_1^2 + 2m_1 + 2m_2^2 + 2m_2 + 1)$

which is an even number.

$z^2 = 4m_3^2 + 4m_3 + 1 = 2(2m_3^2 + 2m_3) +1 $ which is an odd number.

Thus $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ can not hold because an even number cannot equal an odd number. Therefore we have proven that atleast one number is even in an Pythagorean Triple.

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: Correct, but possibly a bit lost in the details. You might argue (equivalently, but possibly more conceptually) that if $x, y$ are both odd, then so are $x^{2}$ and $y^{2}$, so that $z^{2} = x^{2} + y^{2}$ is even, and thus $z$ is even.

Comment: +1 for Andreas Caranti's comment. I find this is a proof method that many (myself included) often overlook. Suppose you have to prove that at least one statement of a list of statements is true. It suffices (in fact is equivalent) to prove that if all but one of the statements of your choosing, say $P$, is false, then $P$ must be true. In symbols $(a\lor b) \iff (\neg a \implies b)$.